# aw_blog: List of latest posts in home page

Tags: magento-1.9, home, blog

I am new in Magento, I installed **aw_blog**, with this extension we can just show latest posts in sidebar but I want to show latest posts in homepage but I don't know how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

In the RWD theme I added the blog posts to the footer by doing the following:

In de local.xml add a new static block to the footer:

```
<reference name="footer">
            <remove name="footer_links"/>
            <remove name="footer_links2"/>
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links_news" after="cms_footer_links">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>footer_links_news</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

And in the static block you add the following line(s):

```
<div class="links news">
{{block type='blog/last' name='blog' blocks_count=6 template='ab_blog/widget_post.ptml'}}
</div>
```

Comment: I add above code in `local.xml` in footer tag, in static block add new block with `id = footer_links_news`, but when i refresh my  site everything's was a mess.